# Can someone tell me mistake in my code?

Tags: events, event-handling, mouseevent, mouselistener

i am trying to capture event when i click on button. I created the button successfully   but i am unable to captured event. can someone helps me to find my error.
So, basically we have created the buttons to be clicked on but we are unable to trap event with button. We have facing problems in registering our class (EventDemo) with MouseEventListener class. Please help us sorting out this problem. Any guidance would be beneficial for us.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
    class EventDemo 
    {
    Frame f;
    JButton b;
    Button b1;
    JTextField jt;
    EventDemo(String s)
    {
    f=new Frame(s);
    jt=new JTextField();
    jt.setBounds(150,40,100,100);
    b=new JButton();
    b1=new Button("AWT:(");
    b.setBounds(40,40,100,100);
    b1.setBounds(40,150,50,50);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(b1);
    f.add(jt);
    System.out.println(this);
    f.addMouseEventListener(new MouseEventListener(this));
//Error:EventDemo.java:23 error: cannot find symbol
//f.addMouseEventListener(new MouseEventListener(this));


    f.setLayout(null);
    //f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(404,404);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MouseEventListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
    EventDemo t;
    MouseEventListener(EventDemo t)
    {
    this.t=t;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e1)
    {
    t.jt.setText("mouse");
    t.f.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    }

    public static void main(String... s)
    {
    new EventDemo("Swing Frame");//new object of EventDemo
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the statement

f.addMouseEventListener(new MouseEventListener(this));

with

f.addMouseListener(new MouseEventListener(this));